# Google Data Studio - Custom Metrics and Drill Down Options When Hovering Over Graph

Tags: looker-studio

I have a times series graph in Google with drill down options for the date fields as well as two custom fields. When I go into view or edit mode and hover over my graph to select custom metrics, they are not showing up.

My time series graph

[image]

Settings for my graph

[image]

[image]

Some of my other times series and graphs on the same page have optional metrics that show up when I hover over them. All the other graphs in my report don't have this problem.

Things I have tried.

- Refreshing Data Source
- Refreshing the page
- Enabling and re enabling the custom metrics

I'm not sure what else to do as I am still somewhat new to using this tool. Any hints would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of reasons:

### 1) [Text Box](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6289367)

One possibility is that the Text Box may be ordered ahead of the [Time Series](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7059697) Chart, thus blocking the top of the chart (Right click on the Text Box and set the **Order** to **Send to back**), however, when the chart is selected, it should show, thus #2 should do the trick:

### 2) Chart Header

It may be currently set to **Do not show**; it can be changed by heading to the **Style Tab** of the respective chart, scrolling down till the **Chart Header** section and selecting **Show on hover** from the drop-down.

[Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/9304c5c4-85f7-4b9a-8c22-230701455299) and a GIF to elaborate:

[image]